# parse: stop short of doing something

Tags: idioms, predicate

> Wisely, he stopped **short of counting his chickens**, but his confidence was clear.
>   ([theage.com.au](http://www.theage.com.au/federal-politics/political-opinion/tony-abbott-puts-a-positive-spin-on-clive-palmer8217s-political-tornado-20140710-zt2zy.html))

There is an idiom, *[stop short of doing something](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stop_1)*. I suppose *[short of doing something](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/short_2#short_2__59)* could be interpreted as a [*predicative adjunct/complement*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/do-predicative-adjuncts-modify-nouns-or-verbs): describing the subject semantically; modifying the verb, *stop*, syntactically. Is it what you have in your mind?

Comment: _Counting one's chickens (before they hatch)_ is also an idiom.

Comment: ..and so is "conscience was clear" an idiom. **Warning~~Mixed Metaphor~~ *Stopping short + counting chickens + clear conscience* .** (This quote didn't come from the Age's *Sports Pages* by any chance, did it? LOL ;-)

Comment: *to stop short* is a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very tricky. What do we have in *stop short of*? Is it **1)** as Jim suggests, a particle phrasal verb (*stop short*) plus an optional PP with *of* as its complement? **2)** an ordinary *stop* with a PP headed by *short of* as a secondary subject-oriented complement? or **3)** a particle-preposition phrasal verb like *put up with*? None of these standard tests yields entirely felicitous results:

> 1a. <sup>?</sup> It was of counting his chickens that he stopped short.
> 2a. <sup>?</sup> It was short of counting his chickens that he stopped.
> 3a. <sup>?</sup> It was counting his chickens that he stopped short of.
>
> 1b. <sup>?</sup> Of counting his chickens was where he stopped short.
> 2b. <sup>?</sup> Short of counting his chickens was where he stopped.
> 3b. <sup>?</sup> Counting his chickens was what he stopped short of.

But the idiom *stop short* does not ordinarily mean *stop before reaching a point*, but *stop abruptly*.

On the other hand, we do have the idiom *fall short*, meaning *fail to reach a given goal.*

And *That is a point short of which I will stop* is not nearly so absurd as Churchill's *That is an impertinence up with which I will not put.*

So on balance I’m inclined to understand *short of* here as a compound pronoun (with *short* in *fall short* as its intransitive variant). If I’m right, then you’re justified in understanding *short of X* as a locative prepositional phrase which is dependent on *stop* and signifies the final location of the subject.